# Basic javascript help (getting output of train stops)

Tags: javascript

When the program is run, I want a prompt appearing with A list of three trains - The (L) Train, The (N) Train, The (S)ix Train and a request to the user to make their selection.

And if the user enters L, I want an alert outputting a message containing the name of the train and a console log output that contains all the stops for that train.

This is my code but I'm not getting anything when I test on the browser. Am I on the right track here?

```
   var lTrain = ["8th Ave", "6th Ave", "Union Square", "3rd Ave", "1st Ave", "Bedford Ave"];
   var nTrain = ["Times Square", "Herald Square", "28th St", "23rd Street", "Union Square"]; 
   var sTrain = ["Grand Central", "33rd St", "28th St", "23rd St", "Union Square", "Astor Place"];

   var trains = alert('The (L) Train, The (N) Train, The (S)ix Train');
   var selection = prompt("Select your train");

  if (selection = L) {
  prompt("The L Train");
  console.log(lTrain) 
  }

  if (selection = N) {
  prompt("The N Train");
  console.log(nTrain)
 }

  if (selection = S) {
  prompt("The S Train");
  console.log(sTrain)
 }
```

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` and `===` are comparison.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong comparison operators. You should be using a comparison operator not assigning a value `=` => Assign `==` checks for equality.

**Reading Material**

[Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this:

```
if (selection === 'S') {
    // code... 
}
```

or

```
if (selection == 'S') {
    // code...
}
```

Put 'L', 'N', and 'S' instead of L, N and S along with comparison (==) or equality (===) operator as per requirement.